# grails: flash scope working in development but not in production

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have two controller actions, one after the other, in which I am using the grails flash scope to "pass" my object data to the second controller action (in the same controller).

This works fine in development mode using the standard H2 database included, but then does not work in production mode where I deploy to a mysql database.   I didn't think this would make a difference (the database), so I'm a bit perplexed.   When I try the exact same thing on the target/production machine, the flash variable comes up null in the second controller action.  I'm able to see the flow from action 1 to action 2, so there is no mystery there.   Do you know what's wrong?  Am running grails 2.2.4.

Comment: The type of database shouldn't affect this.  I'd suggest checking with your browser's dev tools whether there's an extra redirect happening in prod compared to dev mode, as that would clear out the flash.  Alternatively it might be something to do with cacheing - if action 1 posts to action 2 and 2 redirects back to 1 the browser might be reloading the page for action 1 from its cache rather than re-requesting it from the server.

Comment: How do you 'pass' your object data?

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem. If i run grails prod run-app then flash messages do not appear also. Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem. I had a heroku plugin that was dependent on some database session plugin that had something deprecated in it. If i would look in the terminal window and investigate logs i would find this plugin easily. Also i used the `grails dependency-report`command to track which plugin was calling in the broken one.

I removed the heroku plugin and now in production mode my flash messages are showing.

This shows that in some way flash scope is connected to persistence layer. Because i saw such errors in terminal when the flash messages should appear `ERROR databasesession.GormPersisterService - org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsFlashScope Message: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsFlashScope` and a huge stack trace.

What i learned that is by default flash messages are working also in prod mode. But errors can brake this. Also hibernate errors. So, try to eliminate errors. They could be caused by plugins. Maybe some incompatibility plugins. There are plugins that work ok with hibernate4, but not with hobernate3 and vice versa.